# Android AVD error after update to 2.3

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu

(ubuntu8.0.4+eclipse3.6.1+ADT8.0.1)
I update android from(1.5+1.6+2.1+2.2) to 2.3,but I got

1:/home/workaccount/Android/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator: /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.8' not found (required by /home/workaccount/Android/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator)
2:/home/workaccount/Android/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator: /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc.so.6: version`GLIBC_2.11' not found (required by /home/workaccount/Android/android-sdk-linux_86//tools/emulator)

when I start an AVD.
All versions can't work now.
I delete everything expect eclipse,download adt, AndroidSDK, platform2.3/2.2 ,still error.
Heeeelp!!!

Comment: [Try this](http://codetrips.blogspot.com/2010/12/latest-update-for-android-sdk-breaks.html), it worked for me...........<br><br>

Comment: The least system intrusive solution - "The Android team is working on a fix - in the meantime, a workaround is to download the _r07 of the tools from here, and replace emulator in the tools/ folder under the android_sdk installation folder."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade your your system to Ubuntu 10.10 (maverick) everything works fine for android 2.3 (gingerbread). But, it is bad solution. Google should have to work on backward compatibility issue.

Answer (score 0):

if you want your older version, the best way is
copy your all the versions from your old SDK directory `\platforms` to your new SDK's `\platforms` directory. Restart it and use

Comment: None of the versions can work,the same problem.I havenot use diffent directories.